# Question about uniform continuity from Stein's Complex Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

[image]

I know that a function $f$ is uniformly continuous if $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0$ such that $|f(s_1) - f(s_2)| < \varepsilon \, \forall s_1, s_2 $ such that $|s_1 - s_2| < \delta$. How I can get that supremum on $D$?

Comment: What is capital $F$?

Comment: @MikhailKatz I've edited the post. Sorry!

Comment: It’s just by definition of supremum. If you must, choose $\delta$ in the definition of uniform continuity to satisfy $\epsilon/2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given that $\overline{D} \subseteq \Omega$. Note $\overline{D} \times [0,1]$ is a compact subset of $\Omega \times [0,1]$. $F$ is uniformly continuous on $\Omega \times [0,1]$. So given an $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $\delta > 0$ such that:
$$|F(z_1,s_1)-F(z_2,s_2)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \: \text{  whenever  } \: |(z_1,s_1)-(z_2,s_2)|< \delta$$
Now, if $|s_1-s_2| < \delta$ then clearly $|(z,s_1)-(z,s_2)|< \delta$ for any $z\in \overline{D}$.

(just observe $|s_1-s_2| = |(z,s_1)-(z,s_2)|$)

$$\therefore |F(z,s_1)-F(z,s_2)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \: \text{  whenever  } \: |s_1-s_2|< \delta \: , \: z \in \overline{D}$$
$$\therefore \sup_{z \in \overline{D}}|F(z,s_1)-F(z,s_2)| \le \frac{\epsilon}{2} \: \text{  whenever  } \: |s_1-s_2|< \delta$$
$$\therefore \sup_{z \in \overline{D}}|F(z,s_1)-F(z,s_2)| < \epsilon \; \text{  whenever  } \; |s_1-s_2|< \delta$$